# Dotvvm image classification Accuracy Problem

Tags: c#, html, image-classification, dotvvm

I am trying to image classification with Dotvvm and I made everything true but my model accuracy is **0%** and results are **NaN%.** What should I do? Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: DotVVM is a framework for making websites. It doesn't do anything with image classification or image recognition - I guess you are using some library or service for that.